# Capybara, Selenium and Redactor Rich Text Editor

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara, redactor

I've run into an interesting problem with Capybara and Selenium.  I have some Capybara request specs which require javascript to be enabled while a form is being completed.  One of the forms is a textarea which used the Redactor Rich Text Editor.

```
<div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :description, "Description", class: "control-label" %>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: "redactor"%>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the test runs and Selenium fires (in both FF and Chrome drivers), Selenium fails on the following command:

```
`fill_in "Description", with: "some description"`
```

The error it returns is:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidElementStateError:
   Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

It seems that Selenium can't recognize the Rich Text Editor/Textarea any more.  If I remove the `class="redactor"` which is what triggers the Redactor JS to render against the Description text area it works fine.

So my question is, 1. Is there a workaround to fill it out?  2. Alternatively, could I somehow disable the redactor js just for this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like capybara will include the ability to fill_in contenteditable divs (see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/911).

In the meantime I use the following: (you need to have :js => true for your scenario)

```
# fill_in_redactor :in => find(".text1"), :with => "Hello world"
def fill_in_redactor(options)
  if options[:in]
    parent = "('#{options[:in]}').find"
  else
    parent = ""
  end

  page.execute_script( "$#{parent}('.redactor_editor').html('#{options[:with]}')" )
  page.execute_script( "$#{parent}('.redactor').html('#{options[:with]}')" )
end

def no_redactor
  page.execute_script("$('.redactor').destroyEditor();");
end
```

Comment: Thanks - yes this seems to be correct, I came up with this while awaiting an answer `page.execute_script('$("#job_description").val("some text here")')` which seems to be a similar approach.  I like your idea of making it a utility method - i'll definitely do that!  Thank you!

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer because it was a reasonable assumption at the time. However, that pull request has not been accepted and the discussion indicated it won't ever be.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to consider using Redactor's API for filling editor fields:

```
def fill_in_redactor(options)
  if options[:in]
    node = "('#{options[:in]}')"
  else
    node = "('.redactor')"
  end

  page.execute_script( "$#{node}.redactor('set', '#{options[:with]}')" )

end
```

If no :in option is passed, it will find the first field with the .redactor class. Otherwise, it assumes the :in value is a valid css finder value.

This avoids having to manually fill in the hidden text_area field.

Comment: +1 to this method, worth noting that the API has changed to be `.redactor('code.set', '#{options[:with]}')`

Answer (score 4):

As narath mentioned, Capybara now supports contenteditable divs. I was able to write:

`find('.redactor_editor').set('text')`

fill_in wasn't working for me for some reason though.